# Comparing two DataFrames

Tags: r

I have two data frame of the following type:

```
df1
#  ProbeName   Tglult
#1  PDKT_001       NA
#2  PDKT_002       NA
#3  PDKT_003 676.2108
#4  PDKT_004       NA
#5  PDKT_005 724.9720
#6  PDKT_006       NA

df2
# ProbeName    Pglult
#1  PDKT_001        NA
#2  PDKT_002        NA
#3  PDKT_003  648.9933
#4  PDKT_004        NA
#5  PDKT_005        NA
#6  PDKT_006   15.0673
```

I want to see which ones have the same ProbeName with a value in the second column (I don't mind which is this value). Or which ones doesn't. So this should be the expected result:

```
# [1] "PDKT_003" #Both data frames have a values for this row
#With another option get the ones which are in df1 and not df2
# [1] "PDKT_005"
#With another option get the ones which are in df2 and not in df1
# [1] "PDKT_006"
```

**How can this be done?**

At first I thought that `merge` would do and tried:

```
#Which are the ones in common and the ones in the df2 that are not in df1
probe <- merge(x=df2[!is.na(df2[,2]),], y=df1[!is.na(df1[,2]),],
by.x="ProbeName", by.y="ProbeName", all.x=TRUE) 
probe[, 1]
# [1] PDKT_003  PDKT_006

#The ones in common
probe2 <- merge(x=df2[!is.na(df2[,2]),], y=df1[!is.na(df1[,2]),],
by.x="ProbeName", by.y="ProbeName")
probe2[, 1]
# [1] PDKT_003

#The ones in common
probe3 <- merge(x=df2[!is.na(df2[,2]),], y=df1[!is.na(df1[,2]),],
by.x="ProbeName", by.y="ProbeName", all.x=TRUE) 
probe3[, 1]
# [1] PDKT_003  PDKT_005
```

But I think there is be a better way that now matching

```
 common <- match(probe2[,1], probe3[,1])
 probe3[,1][!is.na(common)]
```

I don't know if I missed something or anything (I've been a while around this and something might be wrong)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that - as provided in your example - every ProbeName *is unique* and ordered and occurs at the *same row* for both data frames:

```
> d1 <- data.frame(a=1:6, v=c(NA,NA,1,NA,1,NA))
> d2 <- data.frame(a=1:6, v=c(NA,NA,1,NA,NA,1))

> !is.na(d1$v) & !is.na(d2$v)
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE

> d1[!is.na(d1$v) & !is.na(d2$v),"a"]
[1] 3

> d1[!is.na(d1$v) & is.na(d2$v),"a"]
[1] 5

> d1[is.na(d1$v) & !is.na(d2$v),"a"]
[1] 6
```

Comment: Regarding (already deleted question by Llopis):
I guess it will work, when you "un-factor" the strings in your data frame or keep them from being interpreted as factors by adding stringsAsFactors = FALSE in data.frame(...) or by simply leaving out the (redundant) string parts in ProbeName and store those as integers.

Comment: It was a silly mistake of the `$v`. Thanks! If you add some comments to the code it will be a bit easier for further people.

Comment: no, I think the code is in this case truly sufficiently self-explanatory.